# Alternative to java.nio.file.Path in Java6 for OS File system Flexibility

Tags: java, io, operating-system

I am backporting a code to Java SE6 and I am looking to have a OS agnostic file retrieval for my code. I already have a code on SE7  that works great.

This is the way I am using it on Java SE7.

```
      protected Properties getPropertiesFromFileSystemPath(final String filename) throws IOException {
        if (filename != null) {
          Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("");
          final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(p.resolve(filename).toFile());
          return getProperties(inputStream);
        } else {
          throw new IOException();
        }
      }
```

With this code I can point to a file `foo\bar\file.txt` or `foo/bar/file.txt` and will be found.

Is there is an alternative way as easy as using  `java.nio.file.Path` in Java SE6?

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving aways a single file, using this Path concat function is an overkill.

You can use simply `new FileInputStream(filename)`. It will work correctly on both `/` and `\`, even if you mix them up.

And it is very important that you CLOSE the input stream you opened. In java7 you can use the autocloseable function:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
    return getProperties(is);
}
```

In Java6 you need to close it yourself:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
try {
    return getProperties(is);
} finally {
    if (is != null) is.close();
}
```

Comment: Except you don't need to do `if (is != null) ` because `is` cannot be null at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Boschi for the tip on closing. I found that in at least in Java 6 when accesing a file on the same directory as for example      `.\file.txt`  in windows `file.txt` so I will use the unix file path way for handling files.